# Regex for validating URLs or File locations within Struts 2

Tags: java, xml, regex, validation, struts2

Good day,

I'm looking for a regex that validates URLs and file locations that will work within a struts 2 environment.

What I mean by in a struts 2 environment, is the string will be input into a textfield:

```
<s:textfield name="linkAddr.urlAddress" id="linkAddr" maxlength="2500"/>
```

In struts 2, as you know, if someone inputs **google.ca**, it will return

> **APP_LOCATION/NAMESPACE/google.ca**

, and will not point to google, despite the input normally being correct.

Therefore, I want a regex that will validate to take this into account (user MUST type http, https, ftp, or \\ (in the case of a file located on a shared drive).

EDIT:

Some examples:

I want to allow:

```
http://foo.com/blah_blah_(wikipedia)_(again) 
http://www.example.com/wpstyle/?p=364 
https://www.example.com/foo/?bar=baz&inga=42&quux 
http://✪df.ws/123 
ftp://foo.bar/baz 
http://foo.bar/?q=Test%20URL-encoded%20stuff 
http://1337.net 
http://a.b-c.de 
\\asdf.233.net\natdfs\AAA\HQ\FFEE\FFEE_H0E\GV1\AAA\FFFEEE\Web Dev\Web Applications Team\Web Applications Team Document.docx
```

Comment: can you provide us with some examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for your regex:

```
((http://|https://|ftp://)([\S.]+))|((\\\\)(.+)(\.)(\w+))
```

Your case is a little complicated because of the last one and I think this regex wlil validate some urls that you don't want to be validated, since it's attempting to cover subdomains, etc., too, but you can try it out and make adjustments where necessary.

This regex will check if your string starts with http://, https:// or ftp://, followed by any number of characters besides whitespace or newline, or if it starts with \\ and is followed by any number of characters ending with a file extension (eg, .doc). If it doesn't have a file extension, it will be invalid.

You can test out the regex and anything else you come up with at [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/)!